# Is it not possible to initalize more than 4 variables at once?

Tags: c, initialization, declaration

```
void main() {
    int a, b, c, d, e = 0;

    printf("\n%d", a);
    printf("\n%d", b);
    printf("\n%d", c);
    printf("\n%d", d);
    printf("\n%d", e);
}
```

output:

```
16
0
10818512
0
0
```

For some reason `a` is always equal to 16 although I initialize it to 0.

`c` on the other hand always changes its value when I rerun the code. Why does this happen?

I feel like I am missing out on something important here.

Comment: unrelated: prefer `printf("%d\n", value);` with the newline at the end of the *format string*.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is  a formally complete question.

Comment: @alk (not my vote) "This question does not show any research effort". It would be covered by any reference on initialization. Guessing the language semantics doesn't get far in C

Comment: You're much better splitting up code like `int a, b, c, d, e = 0;` into one line per variable.  You gain nothing from putting them all in one line.  Textbooks do that because over the length of the book that format saves a handful of pages, and over hundreds of thousands of textbooks saving a few pages allows the CEO of the publishing company to pay for his swimming pool.  "Brevity of code" is nothing but a cargo-cult aphorism.  What matters is readability and maintainability.  It's easier to read and maintain code with one variable per line because you can find them and change them easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *a is always equal to 16 although I initialize it to 0*

No, you do not.

This line

```
int a, b, c, d, e = 0;
```

initialises only  `e` to `0`.

All other variables stay uninitialised. Printing might invoke undefined behaviour. The values printed are just something, garbage, undefined.

To initialise `a` as well, do

```
int a = 0, b, c, d, e = 0;
```

---

> *Is it not possible to initalize more than 4 variables at once?*

It is not even possible to (explicitly) initialise more than **one** variables at once.

Comment: Hm, so how do the commas work then? Why are b, c and d initialized to 0?

Comment: @NicolasPeyer: "*Why are b, c and d initialized to 0?*" they aren't. Their values are something, undefined. As you write yourself: "*c on the other hand always changes its value when I rerun the code*"

Comment: Is there a way to initialise mutiple variables at once to the same value?

Comment: "*Is there a way to initialise mutiple variables at once to the same value?*" No, there is not.

Comment: "might" is pretty mild given the standard.

Comment: You can initialize multiple to the same value, a = 1, b = 1, c = 1” etc

Comment: @Fredrik: Not entirely sure what your comment refers to but   doing so "*`a = 1, b = 1, c = 1`*" I feel is not doing initialisation "at once", but in three steps.

Answer (score 3):

Only `e` is initialized to zero. All other variables aren't initialized.
See [Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/initialization) for an explanation

> **Initialization**
>   For *each* declarator, the initializer, if not omitted, may be one of the following:
>
> ...
>
> **Implicit initialization**
>   If an initializer is not provided:
>
> - objects with automatic storage duration are initialized to indeterminate values (which may be trap representations)

So, if you want to initialize each variable, you must provide an initializer for each of them, e.g.

```
int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, e = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

All your variables except for `e` are uninitialized. You need to explicitly initialize them using the assignment operator `=`:

```
int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, e = 0;
...
```

Your printf() statements except the one involving `e` invoke undefined behavior.

You shouldn't rely on undefined behavior. It might appear as if it's working normally and it might not.

Answer (score 1):

All variables in this declaration

```
int a, b, c, d, e = 0;
```

are not initialized except the last variable `e`. They would be zero-initialized if they had the static storage duration. However these variables are local variables with the automatic storage duration and are not initialized by the compiler implicitly.

You need to initialize each variable like

```
int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, e = 0;
```

Another approach if you want to initialize all variables by zero at once is to enclose the variables in a structure like

```
struct { int a, b, c, d, e; } s = { 0 };
```

In this case all variables will be initialized by zero. You can access them like for example `s.a` or `s.b` and so on.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    struct { int a, b, c, d, e; } s = { 0 };

    printf( "s.a = %d\n", s.a );
    printf( "s.b = %d\n", s.b );
    printf( "s.c = %d\n", s.c );
    printf( "s.d = %d\n", s.d );
    printf( "s.e = %d\n", s.e );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
s.a = 0
s.b = 0
s.c = 0
s.d = 0
s.e = 0
```